# what does the @each here do in the ember guides

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm looking at the ember.js guides and am wondering what the `@each` does here?

```
// ... additional lines truncated for brevity ...
allAreDone: function (key, value) {
  return !!this.get('length') && this.everyProperty('isCompleted', true);
}.property('@each.isCompleted')
// ... additional lines truncated for brevity ...
```

Is this jQuery or an ember idiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this jQuery or an ember idiom?

@each is an ember idiom. When you specify that a computed property depends on '@each.isCompleted` ember will refresh the property whenever any of the array element's isCompleted properties change.

See [computed-properties-and-aggregate-data](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) for a detailed explanation.